# Custom Service returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im creating a custom service, where it is working, is returning me in the function service the data, the problem is when i call it in the controller, it is returning me 'undefined'.

Service:

```
var toDoListServices = angular.module('toDoListServices', []);

    toDoListServices.factory('DataTasksService', function($http){
        return {
            getTasks: function(){
                $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
                    return data;
                })

            }
        }
    });
```

Controllers:

```
var toDoListController = angular.module('toDoListController', []);

toDoListController.controller('ListController', ['$scope', 'DataTasksService', function($scope, DataTasksService){
        $scope.tasks = DataTasksService.getTasks();

}]);
```

App.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'toDoListController',
    'toDoListServices'
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTasks` doesn't return anything. A  return inside `success` does nothing.

You need to return the `$http` promise.

Try

```
toDoListServices.factory('DataTasksService', function($http){
    return {
        getTasks: function(){
            // return the promise
            return $http.get('js/data.json');               

        }
    }
});
```

In controller:

```
DataTasksService.getTasks().then(function(response){
    $scope.tasks = response.data;
});
```